# Create type with two possible variants in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in `Typescript` to declare a variable which can be `Int16Array` or `Uint16Array` and nothing more?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript 1.4 has support for [Type Unions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx), the notation is:

```
var arr: Int16Array|Uint16Array;
```

Common methods that both of these have will be available on `arr`. If you use `instanceof` or `typeof` checks on `arr` in conditional/branched code, it will infer the type of `arr` in those branches.

TypeScript 1.4. also has support for type aliases:

```
type My16Array = Int16Array | Uint16Array;
```

You can then use:

```
var arr: My16Array;
```

Comment: Great, help you very much!